# alert if input val = NaN?

Tags: javascript, jquery, calculator, nan

I know this question might have been asked a lot of times but I don't really get the function `isNan()`. I have a calculator and if the result is "NaN" (for example 0 divided by 0), I want to alert 'Doesn't work!'. I thought of something like:

```
function Error() {
    if ($('#result').val() == NaN) {
        alert.('Doesn't work!');
    }
};
```

The result is in the input with the #result. How do i use isNan() here? Can someone help me please? Thanks for responding and sorry for the same question again.

Comment: Everything that comes from HTML is a **String**. I cannot be a Number (or `NaN`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function Error() {
            if(isNaN($('#result').val())){
                alert("Doesn't work!");
            }
        };
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: don't you see  the alert syntax is wrong.

Comment: Thanks @Suchit didn't notice that...

Comment: Thank you alot, it's embarassing for me..